# Is there a reverse function for strstr

Tags: c++, c, string

I am trying to find a similar function to `strstr` that searches a substring starting from the end towards the beginning of the string.

Comment: Umm I am not sure if I should modify this question. But I have one more. Is there a C Library function to find the index to the last occurance of a substring within a string?

Comment: You can get the same effect using strrstr() and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @ManavSharma Why do you ask another question in a comment or consider modifying an existing one? This site is all about questions, you can ask as many as you like. Another question means you create another question on this platform.

Answer (score 12):

The standard C library does not have a "reverse strstr" function, so you have to find or write your own.

I came up with a couple of solutions of my own, and added some testing and benchmarking code together with the other functions in this thread. For those curious, running on my laptop (Ubuntu karmic, amd64 architecture) the output looks like this:

```
$ gcc -O2 --std=c99 strrstr.c && ./a.out
#1 0.123 us last_strstr
#2 0.440 us theo
#3 0.460 us cordelia
#4 1.690 us digitalross
#5 7.700 us backwards_memcmp
#6 8.600 us sinan
```

Your results may be different and, depending on your compiler and library, the ordering of the results may also be different.

To get the offset (index) of the match from the beginning of the string, use pointer arithmetic:

```
char *match = last_strstr(haystack, needle);
ptrdiff_t index;
if (match != NULL)
    index = match - haystack;
else
    index = -1;
```

And now, the larch (note that this is purely in C, I do not know C++ well enough to give an answer for it):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* By liw. */
static char *last_strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    if (*needle == '\0')
        return (char *) haystack;

    char *result = NULL;
    for (;;) {
        char *p = strstr(haystack, needle);
        if (p == NULL)
            break;
        result = p;
        haystack = p + 1;
    }

    return result;
}


/* By liw. */
static char *backwards_memcmp(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    size_t haylen = strlen(haystack);

    if (*needle == '\0')
        return (char *) haystack;

    size_t needlelen = strlen(needle);
    if (needlelen > haylen)
        return NULL;

    const char *p = haystack + haylen - needlelen;
    for (;;) {
        if (memcmp(p, needle, needlelen) == 0)
            return (char *) p;
        if (p == haystack)
            return NULL;
        --p;
    }
}


/* From http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/cordelia/Diplomacy/mapit/strrstr.c
 */
static char *cordelia(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
 const char *sc1, *sc2, *psc1, *ps1;

 if (*s2 == '\0')
  return((char *)s1);

 ps1 = s1 + strlen(s1);

 while(ps1 != s1) {
  --ps1;
  for (psc1 = ps1, sc2 = s2; ; )
   if (*(psc1++) != *(sc2++))
    break;
   else if (*sc2 == '\0')
    return ((char *)ps1);
 }
 return ((char *)NULL);
}


/* From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634359/
   is-there-a-reverse-fn-for-strstr/1634398#1634398 (DigitalRoss). */
static char *reverse(const char *s)
{
  if (s == NULL)
    return NULL;
  size_t i, len = strlen(s);
  char *r = malloc(len + 1);

  for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    r[i] = s[len - i - 1];
  r[len] = 0;
  return r;
}
char *digitalross(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  size_t  s1len = strlen(s1);
  size_t  s2len = strlen(s2);
  const char *s;

  if (s2len == 0)
    return (char *) s1;
  if (s2len > s1len)
    return NULL;
  for (s = s1 + s1len - s2len; s >= s1; --s)
    if (strncmp(s, s2, s2len) == 0)
      return (char *) s;
  return NULL;
}


/* From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634359/
  is-there-a-reverse-fn-for-strstr/1634487#1634487 (Sinan Ünür). */

char *sinan(const char *source, const char *target)
{
    const char *current;
    const char *found = NULL;

    if (*target == '\0')
        return (char *) source;

    size_t target_length = strlen(target);
    current = source + strlen(source) - target_length;

    while ( current >= source ) {
        if ( (found = strstr(current, target)) ) {
            break;
        }
        current -= 1;
    }

    return (char *) found;
}


/* From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634359/
  is-there-a-reverse-fn-for-strstr/1634441#1634441 (Theo Spears). */
char *theo(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
  size_t needle_length = strlen(needle);
  const char* haystack_end = haystack + strlen(haystack) - needle_length;
  const char* p;
  size_t i;

  if (*needle == '\0')
    return (char *) haystack;
  for(p = haystack_end; p >= haystack; --p)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < needle_length; ++i) {
      if(p[i] != needle[i])
        goto next;
    }
    return (char *) p;

    next:;
  }
  return 0;
}


/*
 * The rest of this code is a test and timing harness for the various
 * implementations above.
 */


#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


/* Check that the given function works. */
static bool works(const char *name, char *(*func)(const char *, const char *))
{
    struct {
        const char *haystack;
        const char *needle;
        int offset;
    } tests[] = {
        { "", "", 0 },
        { "", "x", -1 },
        { "x", "", 0 },
        { "x", "x", 0 },
        { "xy", "x", 0 },
        { "xy", "y", 1 },
        { "xyx", "x", 2 },
        { "xyx", "y", 1 },
        { "xyx", "z", -1 },
        { "xyx", "", 0 },
    };
    const int num_tests = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]);
    bool ok = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_tests; ++i) {
        int offset;
        char *p = func(tests[i].haystack, tests[i].needle);
        if (p == NULL)
            offset = -1;
        else
            offset = p - tests[i].haystack;
        if (offset != tests[i].offset) {
            fprintf(stderr, "FAIL %s, test %d: returned %d, haystack = '%s', "
                            "needle = '%s', correct return %d\n",
                            name, i, offset, tests[i].haystack, tests[i].needle,
                            tests[i].offset);
            ok = false;
        }
    }
    return ok;
}


/* Dummy function for calibrating the measurement loop. */
static char *dummy(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    return NULL;
}


/* Measure how long it will take to call the given function with the
   given arguments the given number of times. Return clock ticks. */
static clock_t repeat(char *(*func)(const char *, const char *),
                       const char *haystack, const char *needle,
                       long num_times)
{
    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();
    for (long i = 0; i < num_times; ++i) {
        func(haystack, needle);
    }
    end = clock();
    return end - start;
}


static clock_t min(clock_t a, clock_t b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}


/* Measure the time to execute one call of a function, and return the
   number of CPU clock ticks (see clock(3)). */
static double timeit(char *(*func)(const char *, const char *))
{
    /* The arguments for the functions to be measured. We deliberately
       choose a case where the haystack is large and the needle is in
       the middle, rather than at either end. Obviously, any test data
       will favor some implementations over others. This is the weakest
       part of the benchmark. */

    const char haystack[] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "b"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    const char needle[] = "b";

    /* First we find out how many repeats we need to do to get a sufficiently
       long measurement time. These functions are so fast that measuring
       only a small number of repeats will give wrong results. However,
       we don't want to do a ridiculously long measurement, either, so 
       start with one repeat and multiply it by 10 until the total time is
       about 0.2 seconds. 

       Finally, we measure the dummy function the same number of times
       to get rid of the call overhead.

       */

    clock_t mintime = 0.2 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    clock_t clocks;
    long repeats = 1;
    for (;;) {
        clocks = repeat(func, haystack, needle, repeats);
        if (clocks >= mintime)
            break;
        repeats *= 10;
    }

    clocks = min(clocks, repeat(func, haystack, needle, repeats));
    clocks = min(clocks, repeat(func, haystack, needle, repeats));

    clock_t dummy_clocks;

    dummy_clocks = repeat(dummy, haystack, needle, repeats);
    dummy_clocks = min(dummy_clocks, repeat(dummy, haystack, needle, repeats));
    dummy_clocks = min(dummy_clocks, repeat(dummy, haystack, needle, repeats));

    return (double) (clocks - dummy_clocks) / repeats / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}


/* Array of all functions. */
struct func {
    const char *name;
    char *(*func)(const char *, const char *);
    double secs;
} funcs[] = {
#define X(func) { #func, func, 0 }
    X(last_strstr),
    X(backwards_memcmp),
    X(cordelia),
    X(digitalross),
    X(sinan),
    X(theo),
#undef X
};
const int num_funcs = sizeof(funcs) / sizeof(funcs[0]);


/* Comparison function for qsort, comparing timings. */
int funcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct func *aa = a;
    const struct func *bb = b;

    if (aa->secs < bb->secs)
        return -1;
    else if (aa->secs > bb->secs)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


int main(void)
{

    bool ok = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_funcs; ++i) {
        if (!works(funcs[i].name, funcs[i].func)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s does not work\n", funcs[i].name);            
            ok = false;
        }
    }
    if (!ok)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_funcs; ++i)
        funcs[i].secs = timeit(funcs[i].func);
    qsort(funcs, num_funcs, sizeof(funcs[0]), funcmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_funcs; ++i)
        printf("#%d %.3f us %s\n", i+1, funcs[i].secs * 1e6, funcs[i].name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the length. All the interesting parts (the actual implementations of reverse strstr) are at the top of the code, so should be easy to find.

Comment: You should improve your tests. Haystack and needle too short, try it on large strings.

Comment: If `needle` is empty string, shouldn't `last_strstr` return the end of `haystack` instead of the start?

Comment: I prefer `while (1)` rather than `for (;;)`, it's nicer

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of one. One of the nice things about C is that if you write your own function, it's just as fast and efficient as the library ones. (This is totally not the case in many other languages.)

You could reverse the string and the substring, and then search.

Finally, the other thing people often do when the string library isn't good enough is to move to regular expressions.

Ok, I wrote both `reverse()` and `rstrstr()`, which might work if we are lucky. Get rid of `__restrict` for C++. You also might want to make the parameters `const`, but then you will need to cast the return value. To answer your comment question, you can get the index from the address of the substring by just substracting the original string pointer from it. OK:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(const char * __restrict const s)
{
  if (s == NULL)
    return NULL;
  size_t i, len = strlen(s);
  char *r = malloc(len + 1);

  for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    r[i] = s[len - i - 1];
  r[len] = 0;
  return r;
}

char *rstrstr(char *__restrict s1, char *__restrict s2)
{
  size_t  s1len = strlen(s1);
  size_t  s2len = strlen(s2);
  char *s;

  if (s2len > s1len)
    return NULL;
  for (s = s1 + s1len - s2len; s >= s1; --s)
    if (strncmp(s, s2, s2len) == 0)
      return s;
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: "it's just as fast and efficient as the library ones" That is not true, you can very easily write code in C that is much less efficient than the library one (for example completely botch up your  own "qsort" routine and make O(n^2) and turn it into insertion sort.

Comment: Obviously my statement implies "unless you botch the implementation", but we can't make any statements about anything without including that assumption. I mean, *seriously* now.

Comment: Its easily possible for a library routine to be 10x faster than an algorithmically correct naive implementation. Try writing your own pow( ) function that delivers sub-ulp accuracy and see how you do on performance.  Even in simpler functions, a naive `memcpy( )` might use byte-by-byte copies, where a library implementation might use an unrolled loop of vector copies.

Comment: You guys are missing the overall point, which is that your routine is written in C, the library routine is written in C, everyone is on a level playing field. Let's see someone implement strcmp in Perl, Python, Ruby, or even Java. That's the, ahem, *obvious*, point.

Comment: The library routine is not necessarily written in C. When I'm working on a standard library, I'm usually writing assembly. You could write a C library function in nearly any compiled language that knows about the C calling conventions on the target platform. (That said, I agree that all this is beside the point).

Comment: @Dan, you're wrong. It reverses the sequence of `char` values ignoring any larger multibyte character structure, which `strstr` would ignore anyway. As long as you translate the result back into an offset into the original string, it works just fine with multibyte character strings.

Comment: The standard library almost certainly does not use C; it either uses assembly or C with compiler specific intrinsics. It's basically impossible to make a strrstr as fast as a standard library strstr.

Comment: @Alice GlibC `strstr` is pretty much plain C. Its speed result of a clever searching strategy that will even use a skip table if `haystack` is above a certain length. Using assembly hardly pays off today most of the time as compilers produce better assembly code from C than 9 of 10 devs could by hand and intrinsics only make sense in situations where the CPU can do something, that cannot be expressed in C (like counting the number of 1 bits in an int, almost any CPU can do that, C cannot; or rotate bits of an int) - but none of that is helpful for implementing `strstr`.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use C++, you can search strings like this:

```
std::string::iterator found=std::search(haystack.rbegin(), haystack.rend(), needle.rbegin(), needle.rend()).base();
// => yields haystack.begin() if not found, otherwise, an iterator past-the end of the occurence of needle
```

Comment: and std::w/string::find_last_of

Comment: and even `std::string_view::find_last_of`

Answer (score 3):

One possible, if not entirely elegant, implementation might look like:

```
#include "string.h"

const char* rstrstr(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
  int needle_length = strlen(needle);
  const char* haystack_end = haystack + strlen(haystack) - needle_length;
  const char* p;
  size_t i;

  for(p = haystack_end; p >= haystack; --p)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < needle_length; ++i) {
      if(p[i] != needle[i])
        goto next;
    }
    return p;

    next:;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a bit of nitpicking I would make all of those `const char *`. http://codepad.org/KzryjtRE

Comment: @Kinopiko: Actually, that's not even nitpicking. Leaving the const out would make this function a pain to use for the caller if their "needle" or "haystack" is already const.

Comment: `int` should be `size_t`. But I almost want to upvote for the `goto`.

Comment: You need to make `haystack_end` and `p` and the return value of the function `const char *` too. Please see my paste on codepad.org.

Answer (score 3):

Though non-standard, [strrstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrstr) is widely supported and does exactly what you want.

Comment: Hmmm, it needs to install a lib for such a trivial function. I wish libc had it!

Answer (score 2):

No. This is one of the places that the C++ std::string class has an obvious advantage -- along with `std::string::find()`, there's also `std::string::rfind()`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is one.](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/cordelia/Diplomacy/mapit/strrstr.c) Testing it is an exercise I'll leave to you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can still do it using library functions.

1.Use strrev function to reverse the string.

2.Use strstr function to do whatever you want to do.

3.You can find start index (from reverse ) of the search string by subtracting start index of the search string from the length of original string.

Comment: Going to try this out. Huh .. strrev not found.. looking where it might live.

Comment: `strrev` does not exist in `string.h` on either linux or os/x    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-the-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux

Comment: Be careful doing this - you'll also need to reverse your needle string if you're going to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a C Library function to find the index to the last occurrence of a substring within a string?

**Edit:** As @hhafez notes in a comment below, the first solution I posted for this was inefficient and incorrect (because I advanced the pointer by `target_length` which worked fine in my silly test). You can find that version in the edit history.

Here is an implementation that starts at the end and works back:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *
findlast(const char *source, const char *target) {
    const char *current;
    const char *found = NULL;

    size_t target_length = strlen(target);
    current = source + strlen(source) - target_length;

    while ( current >= source ) {
        if ( (found = strstr(current, target)) ) {
            break;
        }
        current -= 1;
    }

    return found;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if ( argc != 3 ) {
        fputs("invoke with source and search strings as arguments", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const char *found = findlast(argv[1], argv[2]);

    if ( found ) {
        printf("Last occurence of '%s' in '%s' is at offset %d\n",
                argv[2], argv[1], found - argv[1]
                );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> st "this is a test string that tests this" test
Last occurence of 'test' in 'this is a test string that tests this' is 
at offset 27
```

Comment: but that is ugly compared to writing your own routine, what if the string is really long? Also don't forget that he is expecting to have multiple occurrences and he expects to find them towards the end, that's why he wants to start from the end and not from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most minimal simple implantation that I could come up with. Unlike other implementations of this function it avoids the initial strstr call that some other people like user3119703 had.

```
char * lastStrstr(const char * haystack,const char * needle){
    char*temp=haystack,*before=0;
    while(temp=strstr(temp,needle)) before=temp++;
    return before;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it is still starting from the beginning of the "haystack" when searching for the substring (as opposed to starting from the end and searching towards the beginning) as OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is in the c string lib, but it would be trivial to write your own, On one condition, you know the length of the string or it is properly terminated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one in the standard C library. You may be able to find one on the web, or you may have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short:

Nope - there is no function in the C-library that does what you need..

But as others have pointed out: It's not rocket-science to write such a function...

Comment: It's not rocket science to write a slow implementation, but making it fast requires some fancy algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! There is one more way which came from the MSDN forum.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/ed0f6ef9-8911-4879-accb-b3c778a09d94

Answer (score 0):

```
char * strrstr(char *_Str, char *_SubStr){
    char *returnPointer, *p;

    //find 1st occurence. if not found, return NULL
    if ( (p=strstr(_Str, _SubStr))==NULL)
        return NULL;

    //loop around until no more occurences
    do{
        returnPointer=p;
        ++p;
    }while(p=strstr(p, _SubStr));

    return returnPointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard algorithm std::find_end for this purpose. For example

```
    char s[] = "What is the last word last";
    char t[] = "last";

    std::cout << std::find_end( s, s + sizeof( s ) - 1, t, t + sizeof( t ) -1 )
              << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* strrstr(char * _Str, const char * _SubStr)
{
    const BYTE EQUAL=0;
    int i=0, src_len = strlen(_Str), find_len = strlen(_SubStr),
        tail_count=0;

    for(i=src_len; i>-1; i--)
    {
        if(_Str[i] == _SubStr[0] && tail_count >= find_len)
        {
            if(strncmp(&_Str[i], _SubStr, find_len) == EQUAL)
            {
                return &_Str[i];
            }
        }
        tail_count++;
    }
    return NULL;    
}
```

Comment: Explain it a bit too

Comment: @TalhaIrfan With the length of the target string, since at the end to reduce the index to find the desired character string. - google translation