# Is the strrev() function not available in Linux?

Tags: c, string

I tried to write code using `strrev()`. I included `<string.h>` but still I'm getting an "undefined reference to `strrev`" error.

I found that `strrev()` doesn't have man page at all. Why?

Doesn't Linux support `strrev()`?

Comment: I still can't remember the last time I needed to reverse a string.

Comment: When was the last time you had a technical interview? That may well be the only time when a programmer actually needs to reverse a string. That's probably why string.h doesn't even have a string reverse function, but in an interview they wouldn't let you get away with a library function anyway. Well, maybe you would get bonus points for knowing the libraries and being clever, then ask you to implement it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: `strrev()` is not part of any C standard but it is commonly included in some library implementations.

Comment: If you write your own string reversal function, and you're not writing a C library implementation, pick another name. Names starting with `str` and a lowercase letter are reserved to the implementation. `str_rev` is OK.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/string.h) u can find it

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Correct. Use one of the [alternative](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/strrev.c) implementations available:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
      char *p1, *p2;

      if (! str || ! *str)
            return str;
      for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
      {
            *p1 ^= *p2;
            *p2 ^= *p1;
            *p1 ^= *p2;
      }
      return str;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the linked implementation will *not* work if you use a multi-byte character encoding (such as Big5, or any Unicode encoding, in particular UTF-8). But I guess that goes for most `strrev` implementations...

Comment: Ick. That implementation uses six dereferences.  The most you should need is four.

Comment: Dereferences are usually cheap, and certainly sequential dereferences like this would be optimized by the compiler. Unless your compiler sucks.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If you find it trivial to detect that writing to `*p1` does not modify `*p2` in your implementation, allowing to move assignments across read accesses for the purpose of simplifying them, you should write compilers instead of wasting your time on StackOverflow. clang-5.1 -O3 generates three reads and three writes, perhaps you should give them a hand.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yes, three reads and three writes, not nine reads and three writes.

Comment: Good point, I miscounted. The final xor with memory destination should count for one read and one write, and I forgot one read at the beginning. The generated assembly is here. There is nothing to be proud of: http://pastebin.com/MwGVuxYE

Comment: Why on earth would anyone use the XOR swapping trick? Does it make people feel clever? It just makes the code less readable than simply using a temporary variable and may even be slower on modern superscalar out-of-order CPU architectures, because the three statements have data dependencies.

Comment: @Fritz: Not that I'm defending the XOR method, but any in-place reverse operation will be full of dependencies.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Alias analysis can't see that `p2 != p1` in a `for` loop with a condition that is `p2 > p1`? Wow.

Comment: @Fritz Last time I checked (yesterday), I measured it as over 2 times slower than simply using a temporary.

Answer (score 35):

```
#include <string.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
    if (!str || ! *str)
        return str;

    int i = strlen(str) - 1, j = 0;

    char ch;
    while (i > j)
    {
        ch = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = ch;
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This answer is far more readable than the one selected as the "best" answer.

Comment: @FehmiNoyanISI It's also broken. If `str` is empty, `strlen(str) - 1` is garbage. If `strlen(str)` is bigger than `INT_MAX`, you're also going to have problems.

Comment: @melpomene, updated the answer with a `NULL` pointer and empty string check. `strlen()` returns `size_t` and handling `INT_MAX` should be done the library implementation.

Comment: I think the author is not expecting the code but an answer on if it is available under Linux?

Answer (score 6):

To accurately answer your question,

**Is strrev() not available on Linux?**

The functions strrev() available in the string.h library. Functions strrev() including some other string functions such as like strupr(), strlwr(), strrev(), which are only available in ANSI C (Turbo C/C++) and are not available in the standard C-GCC compiler.

It’s not about the system. It is about the C compiler you are using.

References:

https://discuss.codechef.com/t/is-strrev-function-not-available-in-standard-gcc-compiler/2449

https://www.csestack.org/undefined-reference-to-strrev/

Comment: Agreed! Don't want to go on off-track. Deleting the comment. @RichieHH

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `strrev` seems to be absent from glibc's `string.h`.

Obviously, I'm late to the here's-some-code party, but I like this implementation.

```
#define MAX_CHARS 10000
// safe_usub -- perform safe unsigned subtraction
size_t safe_usub (size_t x, size_t y) {
  return x > y ? x - y : y - x ;
}

char* str_reverse (const char* const str) {
  if (!str) { return NULL; }

  size_t len = strnlen(str, MAX_CHARS);
  char*  new = malloc( sizeof(char) * len );

  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    new[i] = str[ safe_usub(i + 1, len) ];
  }

  new[i] = 0;

  return new;
}
```

Comment: Traditionally(the is no specification) `strrev()` performed in place reversal. This code does not.

Comment: @Gerhard it minimises code duplication because I would have to copy the string myself every time I want to use this. I didn't say it was better than other code, I said I liked it more, because I almost never want destructive operations to be in-place. Constructive functions, like the `readln` I use, can be in place.

Comment: this got two upvotes and lasted more than 18 months and nobody realised that the call to strnlen needed 2 arguments

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```c
#include <string.h>

char *strrev(char *s)
{
    if (s && *s) {
        char *b = s, *e = s + strlen(s) - 1;
        while (b < e) {
            char t = *b;
            *b++ = *e;
            *e-- = t;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I think the author is not expecting the code but an answer on if it is available under Linux?

Comment: You are right, I did not answer the OP’s question. Sorry. I saw several possible implementations proposed and I thought mine was better, so I got carried away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no string library function to reverse a string.

`strrev()` Is not present in GCC compiler in Linux.
Make your own reverse function:

`reverse.c`:

```
/*
 * C program to reverse a string using recursion
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char [], int, int);
int main()
{
    char str1[20];
    int size;

    printf("Enter a string to reverse: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    size = strlen(str1);
    reverse(str1, 0, size - 1);
    printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size)
{
    char temp;

    temp = str1[index];
    str1[index] = str1[size - index];
    str1[size - index] = temp;

    if (index == size / 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    reverse(str1, index + 1, size);
}
```

Comment: None of the string functions are present in gcc.  gcc is the compiler. The string functions are provided by the library implementation (for example glibc).

Answer (score 0):

At the time I needed to terminate the source string at a given point, then reverse:

```
// terminate and reverse string
char* tstrrev(char* s, int pt)
{
  char *r = malloc( (pt+1) * sizeof(char) );

    s[pt] = r[pt] = '\0';
    s+= pt - 1;

     while ( *s )
      *r++ = *s--;

 return r-pt;
}
```