# Printing the string value in Reverse

Tags: c, string, printing, reverse

I'm getting a blank output in my console screen when I try to print the string value in a reverse order. If I use for loop for printing the String value is printing, but when I simply print using %s, it is not printing? Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char name1[10],name2[10];
    int i,len,j;

    clrscr();

    printf("\nEnter the string that u want to get reversed:");
    scanf("%s",&name1);
    for(i=0;name1[i]!='\0';i++);
    len=i;

    j=i;

    for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
    {
        name2[i]=name1[j];
        j--;
    }

    printf("\nThe reversed string is:");
    printf("%s",name2);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: A possible duplicate question: [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting your reversed string by placing the nullchar terminator from the original as the first char. Thus as far as `printf()` is concerned, it is an empty string (zero length).

Apart from that, this needs *serious* code review. This is honestly not the place for it, as a review of proper argument would likely rewrite the entire thing (except maybe the beginning `scanf()` and ending `printf()`.  I **strongly** advise you run this step-by-step in a debugger to see what is happening as your code runs.

Comment: And the first of the individual characters written is an ASCII NUL `'\0'` which doesn't appear with a visible representation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If i did the math on the counters on this, I *think* the result is both leading *and* trailing with an ASCI NUL. I've had *way* too much turkey to be that detailed at this point in the evening =P

Comment: For code review: codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

some notes for you:

- format your code properly before posting
- you used too many "printf"s to see variable values.
  that means u don't know how to DEBUG your code properly
  please google for HOW TO DEBUG CODE + "IDE name you are using"
  (fe. HOW TO DEBUG CODE VISUAL STUDIO)
- always add commments to your code
- before posting something like that pls GOOGLE first!
  The "reverse a string" problem is a typical "Inroduction to Programming" assignment
  and it's not hard to find a sample code for that. at the beginning code study is more
  useful than just randomly typing some bulshit code
- you should give your variables more meaningful names
  f.e. in your case 'src' and 'target' are much better choices than name1 and name2
  of course in such a short code it's not important but get used to it asap
- try to solve such problems first on paper for visualization before starting coding
- since you try to deal with dynamic string content by reading input from user, it's a better idea to use dynamic allocation i.e malloc()/free() than using fix arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use the strrev function from the standard string.h library

Comment: Which standard is that? (Hint: it isn't standard in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — the C standard; nor is it standard in POSIX.)

Comment: You're right. Sorry I read it from a bad resource.

Comment: It's likely some other library, and it is likely declared in `<string.h>` when you're using that library, so it might seem like it's 'standard'.  That said, [die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/) does not recognize it, and [Is `strrev()` function not available on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux) suggests that it is not `glibc`, the GNU C library.