# Objective: To examine a user-entered string to determine if it's a palindrome

Tags: c++

Hi everybody I am c++ beginner I am working on program to examine a user entered string to determine if it's a palindrome. I have the most of the code but still  two problems the first one is In function ‘bool PalindromeTest()’and the second error is: error: ‘strrev’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char s[100];
char sr[100];

void InputString();
bool PalindromeTest();
void PrintMessage();

int main()
{
       InputString();
       return 0;
}

void InputString(int n=0)
{
       cout<<"Input the string you wish to be tested";
       cin.getline(s, 100);
       if(strlen(s)>n)
          PalindromeTest();
}

bool PalindromeTest()
{
       bool rvalue = true;
       strcpy(sr, s);
       strrev(sr);
       if(strcmp(s, sr) == 0)
       {
              rvalue=true;
              PrintMessage();
       }
       else
       {
          rvalue=false;
          PrintMessage();
    }
void PrintMessage(bool rvalue)
{
       if(true == rvalue)
         cout<<"The entered string IS a palindrome"<<endl;
       else
         cout<<"The entered strins IS NOT a palindrome"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: For the `strrev` -- look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux

Comment: ]$ g++ uu.cpp
uu.cpp: In function ‘bool PalindromeTest()’:
uu.cpp:32: error: ‘strrev’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: ... so what makes you think that function exist?

Comment: No i think the function doesnt exist and thats why it's showing erroe in the function bool palindrmetest

Comment: If you don't think it exists, why are you trying to call it?

Comment: You'd make things a lot easier for yourself by using `std::string` instead of char arrays

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a C++ question, how about a real C++ solution? With `str` being a `std::string`:

```
bool isPalindrome = std::equal(str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin());
```

Comment: I guess we could optimize that by replacing `str.end()` with `str.begin() + str.size() / 2`

Comment: Yeah, this isn't written for efficiency. But I thought it made for an elegant little one liner. If I needed an efficient solution, I would just loop and compare characters, C style (Edit: That would look very much like the answer @MichaelJ just posted).

Comment: @RetoKoradi - That is a good and simple solution, but I suspect that our questioner might not be ready to understand it.  :-)

Comment: @MichaelJ: It explains itself. It's a palindrome if reading the string in sequence from **begin** to **end** is **equal** to what you get if you **begin** reading in **r**-everse. ;)

Comment: @RetoKoradi - Our friend does not yet understand functions or local variables.  Iterators and std:: algorithms are going to be tough.

Comment: @MichaelJ: Sure. Frankly, fixing the original code, or creating a complete list of all the problems, was just not that interesting. So I thought I might as well have some fun by turning 50 lines of code into 1 line. And show how C++ concepts can be applied to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `strrev()` is a C++ function.

A quick way to identify a palindrome is to use a loop with two counters, say `i` and `j`.

Start with `i=0` and `j=strlen(str)-1` (the last valid character) and iterate `++i` and `--j`, `while i<j`.

If, on any iteration, str[i] != str[i], then it is not a palindrome so you can return false.
If it gets to the end of the loop without finding any difference, then it is a palindrome.

```
bool Palindrome(const char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i, j;
    for (i=0, j=len-1; i<j; ++i, --j)
        if (str[i] != str[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this couse i should replace with what code ? from what line to line ??

Comment: @user3598206 -  Read your own post and try to figure that out.  Did you write the code you posted?  If you did, then I think you can figure that out.  Have a try and post it.  I will help you if it is wrong.

Comment: int main()
 {
       InputString();
       return 0;
 }

 void InputString(int n=0)
 {
       cout<<"Input the string you wish to be tested";
       cin.getline(s, 100);
       if(strlen(s)>n)
          PalindromeTest();
 }
 bool Palindrome(const char *str)
 {
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (i=0, j=len-1; i<j; ++i, --j)
        if (str[i] != str[j])
            return false;
    return true;
 }

Comment: i decleared i and j before the function palindrome and still says i and j was not decrealed

Comment: @user3598206 - Oops.  I made a mistake, not declaring those.  That'll teach me to write code without compiling it.  It is now fixed.

Comment: @user3598206 - I didn't spot your code in the comment above until just now.  Without trying to be rude: I don't think you know enough C++ yet to do this program.  I could give you a solution, but you won't learn like that.  Do you have a C++ text book?  Which one?  I think you will benefit from revising the absolute basics before you go on.  Until you understand how functions and parameters work, this is going to be pretty impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio> 
    #include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

char s[100];
char sr[100];

void InputString();
bool PalindromeTest();
void PrintMessage(bool);

int main()
{
    InputString();

    std::cin.get() ;    
    std::cin.get() ;
    return 0;
}

void InputString()
{
    int n = 0;
    cout<<"Input the string you wish to be tested \n";
    cin.getline(s, 100);
    if(strlen(s)>n)
        PalindromeTest();
}

bool PalindromeTest()
{
    bool rvalue = true;
    strcpy(sr, s);
    strrev(sr);
    if(strcmp(s, sr) == 0)
    {
        rvalue=true;
        PrintMessage(rvalue);
    }
    else
    {
        rvalue=false;
        PrintMessage(rvalue);
    }
    return false ; // ??
}
void PrintMessage(bool rvalue)
{
    if(true == rvalue)
        cout<<"The entered string IS a palindrome"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"The entered strins IS NOT a palindrome"<<endl;
}
```

1. method signatures (name , number of parameters and their types) in forward declarations must be equivalent to their signatures in their definitions .(take a look at declarations and definitions of default and fixed versions of InputString , PrintMessage) .
2. n was undefined .
3. methods with type other than void must return a value , but in your case PalindromeTest does not need to return anything .

here is a better version :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

char s[100];
char sr[100];

void InputString();
bool PalindromeTest();
void PrintMessage(bool);

int main()
{
    InputString();

    std::cin.get() ;    
    std::cin.get() ;
    return 0;
}

void InputString()
{
    cout<<"Input the string you wish to be tested \n";
    cin.getline(s, 100);
    PrintMessage(PalindromeTest());
}

bool PalindromeTest()
{
    strcpy(sr, s);
    strrev(sr);
    if(strcmp(s, sr) == 0)
    {
        return true ;
    }
    else
    {
        return false ;
    }
}
void PrintMessage(bool rvalue)
{
    if(rvalue)
        cout<<"The entered string IS a palindrome"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"The entered strins IS NOT a palindrome"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass rvalue as parameter while calling the PrintMessage().
Think, it will help.