# implicit declaration of function ‘strrev’

Tags: c, palindrome, implicit-declaration

Any ideas on why when I try to compile *this* code to check if a line from the file `atadata` I get the warning:

> `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strrev’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char palindromes[100];
    char reverse[100];
    FILE *atadata = fopen("atadata","r");
    while (fgets(palindromes,sizeof(palindromes),atadata) != NULL){
        strcpy(reverse,palindromes);
        strrev(reverse);
        if( strcmp(atadata,reverse) == 0)
        fputs(atadata, stdout);
    }
    fclose(atadata);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a definition for it in string.h?

Comment: There is no `strrev` unless you have written one. (then you need to include the header with your declaration)

Comment: also Note that fgets include a newline.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I meant declaration, but I'm tired:(

Comment: im new to c thank you for your help! how do you write a strrev??

Comment: @SeanO'Brien You open a text editor, type in the necessary code, save it as a text file and compile it using a C compiler.

Comment: Start at the ends, swap chars and keep going in until you meet in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

If you are compiling in Linux, then `strrev()` is [not part of string.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-the-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux). The linked question contains an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534275/19410) linking to source for an implementation you can bring into your own code directly.

Comment: This link might be useful from Stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-the-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux

Comment: That's the same link that is in my answer.

Comment: Oh! i didn't observe that's good solution actually.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *strrev(char *str){
    char c, *front, *back;

    if(!str || !*str)
        return str;
    for(front=str,back=str+strlen(str)-1;front < back;front++,back--){
        c=*front;*front=*back;*back=c;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase some of the other peices of code are hard to read or you do not know how to use pointers, here is a short script to reverse a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
// Start here
char String1[30] = "Hello",reversed[30];
int i;
long int length = strlen(String1);

//Reverse string
for(i=0; i<length; ++i)
{
    reversed[length-i-1] = String1[i];
}

printf("First string %s\n",String1);
printf("Reversed string %s\n",reversed);

// To here if you want to copy and paste into your code without making functions 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is punk of readable coding style. I love simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

One function that will suit your needs and is efficient in its operation would take the following form:

```
/** strrev - reverse string, swaps src & dest each iteration.
*  Takes valid string and reverses, original is not preserved.
*  If str is valid, returns pointer to str, NULL otherwise.
*/
char *
strrev (char *str)
{
    if (!str) { 
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() Error: invalid string\n", __func__); 
        return NULL; 
    }

    char *begin = str;
    char *end = *begin ? str + strlen (str) - 1 : begin;  /* ensure non-empty */
    char tmp;

    while (end > begin)
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea for random utility functions to spew their complaints to `stdout`/`stderr` without explicit instruction.

Comment: I try to be over-inclusive and at least have the function make noise if it receives invalid input. I agree, with your premise regarding error handling, but providing an error handler along with an example function is guaranteed to muddy the water.

Comment: `char *end = str + strlen (str) - 1;` : if `strlen(str)==0` , `end = &str[-1]`.. UB.

Comment: If you consider that invalid input (and decide to check for it), then `abort()` instead of `return 0` after complaining.