# C Programming Command Line Argument

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < args; i++)
        printf("\n%s", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

As of now this program prints out whatever is written on the command line. How would I make it do this in reverse? For example, if I input "dog" it should say "god".

Comment: I am confused by what you are asking. Elaborate please.

Comment: `argv[i]` --> `strrev(argv[i])`

Comment: When I tried that my compiler gave me an error: "/tmp/ccfecPpz.o:backwards.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `strrev'
/tmp/ccfecPpz.o:backwards.c:(.text+0x3f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `strrev'".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-the-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux

Comment: @John3136 it was  modified by @ Ren. I undo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        char *tmp = argv[i];
        int len = strlen(argv[i]);
        for(int j = len-1; j > -1; --j)
            printf("%c",tmp[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had to initialize j outside the for loop, but after I did that it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd break this down into two smaller tasks.

1. Write a helper function that, given a string, prints it out in reverse order. To do so, you could use a loop that starts at the end of the string and prints each character one after the other, moving in reverse across the array as you go.
2. Call that helper function in `main` inside the loop to print each string in the `argv` array.

Since this looks like a homework assignment, I'll leave it at this. If you're having trouble with step (1), then you may need to review how to do string processing a bit before jumping into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[IDEOne Link](http://ideone.com/CZr8fO)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        for(char* c = &argv[i][strlen(argv[i])-1]; c >= argv[i]; putchar(*c--)) ;
        putchar(' ');
    }
    return 0;
}
```