# Reversing array in c - will not print -

Tags: c, arrays, printf, reverse, fgets

The problem with this code is that it does not actually print anything after the user enters in some text in the command line.

The purpose of the code is to accept the number of lines the user will enter in via command prompt after the file name. Then the user will type something in to reverse. The program is supposed to reverse the user input for each line.

Example Input = the big red dog

Example Output =  dog red big the

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 80

char * reverseWords(char *string);

//argc is the count of cmd arguments.
//each command line argument is of type string
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    //initialize local variables
    int i;
    int N;
    char str[SIZE];

    for(i = 1; i <argc; i++)
    {
        //set N equal to the users number in the command line 
        N = atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    if(argc != 2){//2 means that something is in the argument.
        printf("ERROR: Please provide an integer greater than or equal to 0");
        exit(1);//exit the program
    }else if(N < 0){//We cant have a negative array size.
        printf("ERROR: Please provide an integer greater than or equal to 0");
        exit(1);//exit the program
    }else{
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            /*
            fgets(pointer to array, max # of chars copied,stdin = input from keyboard) 
            */
            fgets(str,SIZE,stdin);

            printf("%s", reverseWords(str)); //<---does not print anything....
        }           
    }
    return 0;
}   


char * reverseWords(char *line){

    //declare local strings 
    char *temp, *word;
    //instantiate index
    int index = 0;
    int word_len = 0;
    /*set index = to size of user input
        do this by checking if the index of line is
        equal to the null-character.
    */
    for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        index = i;//index = string length of line.
    }

    //check if index is less than 0.
    //if not we decrement the index value.

    for(index; index != -1; index--){
        //checking for individual words or letters
        if(line[index] == ' ' && word_len > 0){
            strncpy(word,line,word_len);
            strcat(temp , (word + ' '));
            word_len = 0;

        }else if(isalnum(line[index])){
            word_len == word_len+1;
        }//end if

    }//end loop

    //copy over the last word after the loop(if any)
    if(word_len > 0){
        strncpy(word,line,word_len);
        strcat(temp,word);
    }//end if
    line = temp;
    return line;
}//end procedure
```

Comment: `temp` is uninitialized and doesn't point at anything, so you can't pass it to `strcat`.  `(word + ' ')` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: Why don't you use `strlen()` to get the length of the input line?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use C's standard string functions like `strlen()` and `strtok()`? But you're allowed to use `strcat()` and `strncpy()`?

Comment: What is this `word_len == word_len+1;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should come without surprise that `reverseWords` prints nothing. Why?

```
char * reverseWords(char *line){
    ...
    char *temp, *word;
    ...
    line = temp;
    return line;
} //end procedure
```

Where is `line` pointing? (to `temp`). Where was `temp` declared? (in `reverseWords`). How much storage was allocated to `temp` (none -- it is an uninitialized pointer)

Further, what happens to the memory associated with the function `reverseWords` when it returns? (it's destroyed...), so even if you had done something like `char temp[strlen(line)+1] = "";`, `reverseWords` would venture off into *Undefined Behavior* because the pointer you return, points somewhere within the `reverseWords` stack frame that was destroyed when `reverseWords` returned...

How do you fix this? You have three options, (1) pass a second pointer to a second array with sufficient storage, e.g.:

```
char *revwords (char *rline, char *line)
```

or, (2) *dynamically allocate* storage for `temp` so that the memory associated with `temp` survives the return of `reverseWords`, or

(3) use an adequately sized array for `temp` in `reverseWords` and overwrite `line` with the data in `temp` before the return. (e.g. use `strcpy` instead of the assignment `line = temp;`)

While dynamic allocation is straight forward, and creating a separate array in `reverseWords` is fine, you are probably better passing a second sufficiently sized array as a parameter to `reverseWords`.

It is completely unclear what you are doing with the `argc` and `argv` arguments in your code, the arguments to `main` have been omitted from the example below. The following is a short example of reversing the words in each line read from `stdin`,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 256

char *revwords (char *rline, char *line);

int main (void) {

    char line[SIZE] = "", rline[SIZE] = ""; /* storage for line/rline */

    while (fgets (line, SIZE, stdin)) { /* for each line on stdin */
        printf ("\n line: %s\nrline: %s\n", line, revwords (rline, line));
        *rline = 0; /* set first char in rline to nul-byte */
    }

    return 0;
}

char *revwords (char *rline, char *line)
{
    size_t lnlen = strlen (line);   /* length of line */
    /* pointer, end-pointer, rev-pointer and flag pointer-to-space */
    char *p = line + lnlen - 1, *ep = p, *rp = rline, *p2space = NULL;

    if (!line || !*line) {  /* validate line not NULL and not empty */
        fprintf (stderr, "revwords() error: 'line' empty of null.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (*ep == '\n')    /* if line ends in '\n' -- remove it */
        *ep-- = 0;
    else                /* warn if no '\n' present in line */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: no POSIX '\\n' found in line.\n");

    for (; ep >= line; ep--) {  /* for each char from end-to-beginning */
        if (*ep == ' ') {               /* is it a space? */
            size_t len = p - ep;        /* get the length of the word */
            strncat (rp, ep + 1, len);  /* concatenate word to rline  */
            if (p == line + lnlen - 1)  /* if first word, append ' '  */
                strcat (rp, " ");
            p = ep;                     /* update p to last ' '  */
            p2space = ep;               /* set flag to valid pointer */
        }
    }
    strncat (rp, line, p - line);       /* handle first/last word */

    if (!p2space) { /* validate line contained ' ', if not return NULL */
        fprintf (stderr, "revwords() error: nothing to reverse.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return rline;   /* return pointer to reversed line */
}
```

**Note:** if there is no `'\n'` present in `line` when passed to `revwords`, you are likely trying to read a line longer than `SIZE` chars (or you are reading the *last* line where there is no POSIX `'\n'` at the end of the file), and you need to handle that as required. Here I simply warn.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ printf "my dog has fleas\nmy cat does too\n" | ./bin/str_rev_words

 line: my dog has fleas
rline: fleas has dog my

 line: my cat does too
rline: too does cat my
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. There are dozens of ways to approach this problem, no one more right than another if they properly handle the reversal in a reasonable efficient manner. Take your pick.

If you like using the string library functions instead of pointer arithmetic, you could always do something like the following:

```
char *revwords (char *rline, char *line)
{
    /* length, pointer, end-pointer, pointer-to-space, copy of line */
    size_t len = strlen (line);
    char *p = NULL, *p2space = NULL, copy[len+1];

    if (!line || !*line) {  /* validate line not NULL and not empty */
        fprintf (stderr, "revwords() error: 'line' empty of null.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (line[len-1] == '\n')    /* remove trailing newline */
        line[--len] = 0;
    else                /* warn if no '\n' present in line */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: no POSIX '\\n' found in line.\n");

    strncpy (copy, line, len + 1);  /* copy line to 'copy' */

    /* for each ' ' from end-to-beginning */
    while ((p = strrchr (copy, ' '))) {
        strcat (rline, p + 1);          /* append word to rline */
        strcat (rline, " ");            /* followed by a space  */
        p2space = p;                    /* set p2space to p     */
        *p2space = 0;                   /* nul-terminate copy at p */
    }

    if (p2space) {              /* validate space found in line */
        *p2space = 0;           /* nul-terminate at space       */
        strcat (rline, copy);   /* concatenate first/last word  */
    }
    else {                      /* no ' ' in line, return NULL  */
        fprintf (stderr, "revwords() error: nothing to reverse.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return rline;   /* return pointer to reversed line */
}
```

**Note:** While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `caMelCase` or `MixedCase` variable or funciton names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. Leave `caMelCase` or `MixedCase` for java or C++. (it's style, so it's your choice, but it does say something about your code on first impression)

Comment: ... unless your C code uses Xlib, where mixed case is unavoidable

Comment: Granted, but unless you wrote Xlib -- it's not within your control at that point.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you like difficulties.

Adopt this for your purposes

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* reverse_words(char* str);

int main() {
    char arr[] = "the big red dog"; 
    printf("%s", reverse_words(arr));
    return 0;
}


char* reverse_words(char* str) {
    char delim = ' '; // space  
    int left = 0;
    int reverse_index = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);
    char tmp;
    while (left < len) {
        while  (str[right] != delim && right < len)
            right++;    
        reverse_index = right - 1;
        while (left < reverse_index){
            tmp = str[left];
            str[left] = str[reverse_index];
            str[reverse_index] = tmp;
            left++;
            reverse_index--;
        }
        right++;        
        left = right;
    }

    strrev(str);
    return str;
}


//output is: dog red big the
```

if you have no strrev  due to some reasons, here you are

```
char* strrev(char *str) {
  char *p1, *p2;

  if (! str || ! *str)
        return str;

  for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1;
                          p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2) {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
  }

  return str;
```

}

also more clear way, but more slow too

```
char* strrev(char *str) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = strlen(str) - 1;
    char tmp;
    while(left < right) {
        tmp = str[left];
        str[left] = str[right];
        str[right] = tmp;
        left++;
        right--;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that `strrev()` is not available on every platform. See [Is the strrev() function not available in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-the-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux).

Comment: @datell added , hand made one, fo this case

Comment: Great! You could check the platform using the preprocessor like `#if defined(__MACH__) || defined(__linux__) the custom implementation #endif` or something similar. That would be very *C-styled* i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 80

char *reverseWords(char line[SIZE]){
    char temp[SIZE];
#if SIZE > 255
    unsigned index[SIZE];
#else
    unsigned char index[SIZE];
#endif
    int i, index_count = 0;
    int inside_word = !!isalpha((unsigned char)line[0]), word = inside_word;

    for(index[index_count++] = i = 0; line[i]; ++i){//copy & make index table
        unsigned char ch = temp[i] = line[i];
        if(inside_word && !isalpha(ch) || !inside_word && isalpha(ch)){//Edge
            index[index_count++] = i;
            inside_word = !inside_word;
        }
    }
    index[index_count] = i;

    int last_word_index = index_count - 1;//last index
    last_word_index -= !word  ^ (last_word_index & 1);//to word

    char *p =line;
    for(i = 0; i < index_count-1; ++i){
        int len;
        if(word){
            len = index[last_word_index+1] - index[last_word_index];
            memcpy(p, &temp[index[last_word_index]], len);
            last_word_index -= 2;
        } else {
            len = index[i+1] - index[i];
            memcpy(p, &temp[index[i]], len);
        }
        word = !word;
        p += len;
    }

    return line;
}

int main(void){
    char str[SIZE];

    while(fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)){
        printf("%s", reverseWords(str));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be simplified if you used more of the `string.h` functions, like `strlen`. Also, you must dynamically allocate memory with `malloc` and `calloc`--a fixed sized buffer will not do here.

I now present the revised `reverseWords`.

```
char *myrev(const char *line)
{
    char *revword(char *);

    size_t i = strlen(line);
    int inword = OUT;

    size_t nWord = 0, nallocWord;
    char *word;     // will store the word

    size_t nRet = 0, nallocRet;
    char *ret;      // will store the entire line, but reversed

    // establish preconditions
    assert(i > 0);
    assert(line != NULL);

    // alloc memory for word and ret
    if ((word = malloc(nallocWord = INITALLOC)) != NULL && 
                (ret = calloc(nallocRet = INITALLOC, sizeof(char))) != NULL) {

        // walk backwards through line
        while (i--) {
            if (inword == OUT && isalnum(line[i]))
                inword = IN;    // we just entered a word

            if (inword == IN && isalnum(line[i])) {
                // we're inside a word; append current char to the word buffer
                word[nWord++] = line[i];

                // word buffer exhausted; reallocate
                if (nWord == nallocWord)
                    if ((word = realloc(word, nallocWord += ALLOCSTEP)) == NULL)
                        return NULL;
            }

            // if we are in between words or at the end of the line
            if (i == 0 || inword == IN && isspace(line[i])) {
                inword = OUT;
                word[nWord] = '\0';

                word = revword(word);

                // ret buffer exhausted; reallocate
                if (nRet + nWord > nallocRet)
                    if ((ret = realloc(ret, nallocRet += ALLOCSTEP)) == NULL)
                        return NULL;

                // append word to ret
                strcat(ret, word);
                strcat(ret, " ");
                nRet += nWord + 1;

                nWord = 0;
            }
        }
        free(word);

        // remove trailing blank
        ret[strlen(ret) - 1] = '\0';
        return ret;
    }
    // in case of mem alloc failure
    return NULL;
}
```

I will now explain the operation of this function.

The first line declares the function `revwords`, which I will show later.

The next lines are the variable definitions. The variable `i` will be used as an iterator to walk backwards. We initialize it to the length of the `line` string, including the zero terminator.

The variable `inword` is important. It is used to keep track of whether we are inside a word or not. It will be assigned one of two constants: `IN` and `OUT`.

```
#define IN      0    /* inside a word */
#define OUT     1    /* outside a word */
```

The `nWord` and `nallocWord` variables are respectively the number of characters in the `word` buffer, and how much memory is allocated for `word`. `word` is where we will accumulate a word. Since the input line will be parsed backwards, the `word` buffer will be initially backwards, but we will later reverse it.

The variables `nRet` and `nallocRet` have similar purpose: they are respectively the number of characters in the `ret` buffer and the number of characters allocated for `ret`. `ret` is the buffer where we will store the entire input line, but with each word's position reversed.

We then enforce two preconditions: The length of the string must be positive, and the `line` input buffer must not be NULL. We enforce these by using the [`assert`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=assert&sektion=3) macro from `<assert.h>`.

We now enter the meat of the function. Our strategy in this function will be to seize a certain amount of memory initially for our `word` and `ret` buffers, and then later increase the size of our buffer if need be. So we do just that.

The line

```
if ((word = malloc(nallocWord = INITALLOC)) != NULL && 
                (ret = calloc(nallocRet = INITALLOC, sizeof(char))) != NULL) {
```

appears frightening at first, but if we split it into two parts, it will be easier. The part to the left of the AND operator allocates INITALLOC characters for `word`, and checks if the return value is not NULL (indicating failure). But `INITALLOC` is assigned to `nallocWord`, which, as we said earlier, is the number of characters allocated to `word`.

The part to the right of the AND allocates INITALLOC characters for `ret`, and checks if the return value is not NULL. But `INITALLOC` is assigned to `nallocRet`. Notice that we used the [`calloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) function instead of `malloc`. The difference lies in the fact that `calloc` zero-initializes its return value, but `malloc` does not. We need our `ret` buffer to be zero-initialized; you will see why later.

```
#define INITALLOC 16   /* number of characters initially alloc'ed */
#define ALLOCSTEP 32   /* number of characters to increase by */
```

The values of these macros don't really matter, but you should still choose sensible values for them so that too many (slow) re-allocations aren't performed.

Anyway, inside of this `if` statement, we have the while loop which iterates the string `line` from the end. The while loop consists of a series of tests.

1. If we are outside a word (`inword == OUT`) and the current character(`line[i]`) is alphanumeric(i.e, a character inside a word), then we change `inword` to `IN`. Control will fall through to the next `if`, which is
2. If we are inside a word (`inword == IN`) and the current character is a word character, then we add the current character to the end of `word`, and increase the character count `nWord`. Within, we check if `word` has been exhausted, in which case memory is reallocated. If the reallocation fails, we return `NULL`. The reallocation works by increasing `nallocWord` by `ALLOCSTEP`, which is by how many characters we will resize our buffer.
3. If we are in between words (`inword == IN && isspace(line[i]`), or if we are at the end of the line `(i == 0)`, then we change `inword` to `OUT`, null-terminate `word`, and reverse it with a call to `revword`. Our next step is to add the `word` to the end of `ret`. However, we must first check if there is enough space for the concatenation to take place. The condition `nRet + nWord > nallocRet` checks if the number of characters in `ret` plus the number of characters in `word` exceeds `nallocRet`, which the number of characters allocated for the `ret` buffer. If the condition is true, memory is reallocated. If the reallocation fails, we return `NULL`. We need the check `i == 0`, because when the loop is about to finish, we want to push the final word into `ret`.

Now, we can append `word` to `ret` with a call to `strcat`. We also add a space, so that the words will have spaces between each other.

nRet is updated to the new number of characters in `ret`. The `+ 1` is to account for the space in between words. nWord is set to 0, so the next loop iteration will overwrite the old contents of `word`, which are no longer needed.

Once the loop is completed, we release `word`, since it is longer needed, and then remove the trailing space at the end of `ret`. We then return `ret`. It is the caller's responsibility, by the way, to release this memory. For every call to `malloc`/`calloc`, there must be a corresponding `free`.

Let us now turn to `revword`, which is the function to reverse a string.

```
char *revword(char *word)
{
    char *p, *q;

    assert(word != NULL);
    assert(*word != '\0');

    for (p = word, q = word + strlen(word) - 1; q > p; ++p, --q) {
        char tmp;

        tmp = *p;
        *p = *q;
        *q = tmp;
    }

    return word;
}
```

The function uses two character pointers, `p` and `q`. `p` is assigned to point to the start of `word`, whereas `q` is assigned to point to the end of `word`. The `p` pointer is incremented each loop iteration, and `q` is decremented, while `q` is greater than `p`. In the loop body, we swap the values pointed to by `p` and `q`.

Finally, we return the reversed `word`.

Now, I will show the little bit of `main` which I altered.

```
fgets(str, SIZE, stdin);
str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';

char *myrev(const char *line);

char *res = myrev(str);

printf("%s", res);
free(res);
```

This is inside the loop `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)`.

We must remove the trailing newline from the `str` buffer, which `fgets` left in there. We then declare the `myrev` function, and next stored the return value of `myrev` in a temporary, so that we can use this pointer when we `free` it.