# in C, I'm looking for a simple solution for my code that works until a word with 8 or more letters is entered

Tags: c, arrays

I'm pretty very relatively new to C, I'm trying to reverse a string with this code and it works until a word with 8 or more letters is entered and I don't quite understand why.

```
int main()
{
  char string[50], newString[50];
  int end, x;

  printf("Enter a string: \n");
  scanf("%50s", string);

  end = strlen(string);

  printf("%d\n", end);

  for(x=0; x < end; x++){
      newString[(end - 1) - x] = string[x];
  }

printf("%s", newString);
}
```

little bit strange wording of the question but it wouldn't let me ask the question since 'my title was too similar to other questions asked' even I have looked and haven't found what I want to know.

Comment: Hello, you want to change your statement newString[(end-1)-x] = string[x];
to newString[x] = string[end-1-x] .

Secondly, as I see there should be no length limit except 50, are you sure its not because you are using a string with spaces?

Comment: tried it, this doesn't do anything different, my code still doesn't work for words bigger than 7 letters. yea my input word is "abigword", no spaces.

Comment: have you tried initializing `newString` to all NULLs or otherwise appending a NULL to the end of `newString`?

Comment: is there a reason that this would work? I'll try it but if the code works for a 4 letter word such as "test", why would this change be necessary for a word bigger than 7 letters. Edit: ok just tested this, it works now though still unclear as to why, but thanks regardless.

Comment: See my answer below for the explanation

Comment: `scanf("%50s", string);` writes one beyond the end of your string array for strings with greater-than or equal to `50` chars. `scanf` requires `'n-1'` as the *field-width* modifier to the `"%s"` conversion specifier. (which stops reading on encountering the 1st whitespace). Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf`... (and at minimum **check the return** for whatever function you use)

Answer (score 0):

You have not added a NULL terminator to the end of your `newString` buffer.  Try adding this line after the loop, and before you print out.

```
newString[end] = '\0';
```

You code as it is would produce random results depending on what the runtime has placed in the `newString` buffer.  If you're lucky there will be a NULL terminator at the right spot, but it seems like you are unlucky with short strings.

Comment: This will fail miserably with a string such as "this isn't going to work at all.".

Comment: Yes. The OP's scanf will only work with a single string.  So, he will need a more sophisticated mechanism to read in a string if the specified input allows spaces or other special characters in the input.

Answer (score 0):

what bruceg said should work, but in general you should probably get in the habit of initializing the variables you use.

```
char string[50] = {0};  //declare and initialize to zero all elements before it is used.
char newString[50] = {0};
int x = 0;
int end = 0;
```

This way when you copy into newString you know that newString[i] is 0 and %s will hit the null terminator after the copy is done.

Answer (score 0):

> in C, I'm looking for a simple solution for my code that works until a
>   word with 8 or more letters is entered

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 15
void trim_newline(char str[]);

int main()
{
    char s[MAX + 1] = "";

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(s, MAX, stdin);
    trim_newline(s);
    if (strlen(s) >=8)
    {
        printf("Len >= 8\n");
        printf("Quitting ...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("s = %s\n", s);
        printf("Length of s = %d\n", (int)strlen(s));
        printf("Reversed s = %s\n", strrev(s));
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
// -----------------------
void trim_newline(char str[])
{
    if(str[strlen(str) -1] == '\n')
        str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

strrev() reverses a string. No need to redo it, unless your teacher asked for it specifically. fgets() is a secure way to get strings. If a newline is found, it must be trimmed. You can add the condition about zero-length (user pressing Enter only) yourself.

Comment: ok I copied your code exactly into my C workspace and got "error: implicit declaration of function 'strrev'; did you mean 'strlen'?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-the-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux

Comment: Or did you use #include <string.h> (if you are on windows)? It is helpful to say, in general, how your workspace is configured.

Comment: I did use #include <string.h> and on a mac. It's not really a big deal anyway since I know how to do it myself but thanks for the help anyway